# How to get notified about comments in my group in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I have a group on Facebook where folks can ask a question inside a comment. I want to be able to response on this comments quickly, but Facebook doesn't notify me about comments in the group, only about publications and other stuff. Is there any settings to enable it?

I've sent request to FB support, but didn't get any answer yet.

Comment: Facebook has improved their tools for groups administration. Now notifications are displayed correctly. The question is not relevant anymore.